# IE downloads and installs CAB dialog popup upon every page refresh

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, cab

I have a signed cab on an aspx page. I am seeing the following inconsistent behavior. Any  insights would be highly appreciated.

1. On some machines, the cab is downloaded and installed on every page refresh.
2. On few of those machines, the IE "install cab" dialog pops up on every page refresh, while on the others it pops up only once.

Additional info:

1. The CAB contains a .NET DLL
2. The CAB is slightly large (around 30 MB), hence recurring download behavior is a pain

Target browsers are IE6 and IE7, and the behavior is common to both!

Answer (score 0):

Check your zone settings for the various users.  We had the same trouble and fixed it by adding the site to the [trusted zone](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360).

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what exactly the CAB contains, and how you're referencing it?  This is the behavior you'd see if you attempted to install a DLL that would contain an ActiveX control and the ActiveX control isn't registered properly.